# Is onshore vs offshore folks the new way of discrimination in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, abuse

Is onshore vs offshore folks the new way of discrimination in Stack Overflow?

This discussion have a reference to the question [Failed: No element found using locator:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532943/failed-no-element-found-using-locator) where OP mentioned:

> I need to use xpath functions by that way can make proper automation without searching for attributes

Clearly, the OP wanted to use XPath but the main aim was not super clear.

Now one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532943/failed-no-element-found-using-locator/54540367#54540367) states:

> I don't understand why people insist on using XPaths when they aren't needed

However there are three active *tags* on Stack Overflow related to XPath: [`xpath`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath), [`xpath-1.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath-1.0) and [`xpath-2.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath-2.0).

Finally, the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532943/failed-no-element-found-using-locator/54540367#comment95883063_54540367) supporting this comment read as:

> In my experience, it seems to be offshore folks who really love to use xpath.

I am still not sure if this is a case of any of:

- *harassment, bigotry, or abuse*
- *unfriendly or unkind*
- *no longer needed*
- *moderators attention*

So what can be our take on these comments?

Comment: Have you flagged that last comment?

Comment: Offshore - from where?

Comment: "Is onshore vs offshore folks the new way of discrimination in StackOverflow?" No, one person posted a comment that doesn't even really make sense that used the word offshore to refer to a group of people. One person doing something, whether or not it's an attempt to discriminate against some group they're calling offshore,  does not mean that Stack Overflow has a new way of discriminating against people at all, it means one person wrote something stupid.

Comment: Just flag as unkind or rude, and move on. Nothing to see here.

Comment: And you say "comments" plural, have you seen more than one case where offshore has been used in a way that can be slightly misconstrued as an attempt at discrimination? Becuase this [Sede Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/976956) I just threw together pulled up all 181 undeleted comments older than a week containing the word "offshore" and I see absolutely nothing discriminatory in them, so there is no sort of pattern like you seem to indicate by referring to multiple comments.

Comment: From the _onshore vs offshore_, I am assuming you are referring to companies having staff in US/Europe (onsite or onshore) and employees working remotely from  _offshore_ countres like India... No, there is no way for SO itself to discriminate in this case. Its just stray comments that you would flag

Comment: @SurajRao Offshore really just means [a location outside of one's national boundaries, whether or not that location is land- or water-based](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/offshore.asp); Germany is offshore of Russia, just as Mexico is offshore of Canada. Trying to narrow it down to somehow claim it's referring to employees working remotely from countries like India (and what qualifies a country to be "like India", that would be another can of worms) is stretching a term farther than the person who wrote it can really be saying.

Comment: I really don't think this question is suggesting that Stack Overflow as a whole is discriminatory in that regard, it's just asking if that comment is a form of discrimination.

Comment: It's... one comment. Do you notice a bigger trend than that ONE comment? Cause if it's that, I mean..... it's one person being biggoted. How is that all of a sudden an SO problem.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: A new form of discrimination "in Stack Overflow". That is a tacit implication that the site as a whole is responsible. If the OP didn't intent to level a charge at the site specifically, why did the OP deign to name it? And if the intent wasn't to make an accusation, why not just flag it and move on? Why bring it to MSO?

Comment: @NicolBolas I just read "in Stack Overflow" as meaning more generally "here" without any further implication, but of course I could be wrong, I'm really just guessing at what they meant, and I hope they clarify it.

Comment: And if I saw that comment, I probably wouldn't go as far as asking on MSO, since it can definitely be deleted as _useless_ regardless of anything else about it, but I would be curious what it meant, because I've never heard "offshore" used in that context, and it does sound like it's intended to be derogatory.

Comment: I mean... How is offshore even an insult? Is it akin to "that question is really coming out of the left field"? That is like, hardly discrimination, lol.

Comment: I can't really understand, what is "offshore" in this context.

Comment: @peterh As an American in the IT industry, in my experience "offshore" typically means a team in India. I'm guessing that's probably the way it was intended here. It's not a derogatory term in itself but could be used to classify a group of people in a derogatory way.

Comment: As you know, I made the comment, "I don't understand why people insist on using XPaths when they aren't needed". XPath was created to locate elements in XML but has been adapted to find elements in HTML also. The existence of the various XML-related tags doesn't prove their usefulness in locating elements using Selenium. As I've posted many times before, if you read or listen to the Selenium contributors in various SeleniumConf and related talks, you will hear them state over and over NOT to use XPath. You should take their advice, even if others don't.

Comment: @JeffC I think the literal meaning of "offshore" should be someone on a different continent, i.e. also Europe or Australia. I see nothing bad in XPath, and in XML, and I find the current general industrial tendency to leave them, in general, a bad tendency. But I admit, I nearly never had to use any complex xml or xpath for any practical tasks. What is the problem of the Selenium developers with it?

Comment: @JeffC [This](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-choosing-xpath-as-a-locator-not-considered-a-good-practice-in-selenium) link reasons the discouraging of Xpath with same bad practices (hardcoded absolute pathes). But any technology can be used badly, doing the same from procedural code would be similarly bad practice. I find the reasoning bad, and disagree the selenium developers.

Comment: @peterh That blog post is not by a Selenium dev. Having said that, I agree with you that tech can be used badly but that's not why the Selenium devs are warning people away from XPath. There are a number of reasons... performance, different implementations in different browsers, lack of support or reduced support on some browsers, more complicated syntax, and so on. Here's one Selenium contributor's (Dave Haeffner) take on [XPath vs CSS](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/32-xpath-vs-css). You can also look up several talks by Simon Stewart where he states XPath is bad/should be avoided.

Comment: @JeffC Selenium developers obviously focus to HTML, what is not exactly XML (since the another harmful killing of XHTML) and I think css selectors are more native there. Also css selectors have a better syntax. In Selenium is it imho a convincing argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's *not* needed.

The comment is not clarifying, quantifying or supporting the question or answer in any way, shape or form, and is thus irrelevant and subject to being culled in a timely fashion.

Flag it as "not needed" or "unkind", either of those work for this case.  Flag it as "abuse" when it's directed *at* someone.

Comment: "*Flag it as "abuse" when it's directed at someone.*" It *is* directed at someone: the OP. It's the OP who wants to use XPath, so it's accusing the OP of being "offshore" or whatever.

Comment: Your answer have hit the right chord. It would be more helpful to get canonical with the classification as either a _harassment, bigotry, or abuse_, _unfriendly or unkind_, _no longer needed_ or should invite _moderators attention_.

Comment: @NicolBolas is it abuse if the word carries no inherent meaning? Using it over and over with a mean tone could be harassment, but we don't even know what "offshore" is meant to mean.

Comment: "Offshore" => "on a boat"?  So could be playing to a meme rather than being abusive?  Ripe for being culled as "not needed", of course.